# takes ages to boot

Tags: boot

I'm a newbie to ubuntu so please be patient with me. My laptop (satellite L350  takes ages and ages to boot (around 2 and a half minutes). Here is the contents of my fstab file, as I've been told this will help you diagnose the problem. It runs fsck at every boot, which i can't turn off by editing some line in a terminal to 0 (can't remember which, but found it on here about stopping fsck running)  Thanks in advance.

```
 <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c92c26b5-042d-4aa5-ad7e-49f54fb0b66e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5e13e939-d71d-45b9-aa5d-fb31cdf4fa4a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: `fsck` is file system check - if its running every time you boot, I'd guess the system is being `shutdown` correctly.  Do you shutdown your system? or just pull out the power cord (hold down power button etc) or did you purposely (or accidentally) add the `fsck` [`tune2fs`] to each boot cycle? as yes it takes time to check your filesystem.  (*a fsck on boot up normally occurs around every 30th boot unless a problem is detected*)

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using an old laptop with not so good configuration.  So, if you use any of the recent versions of Ubuntu, it may have compatibility issues. Which version of Ubuntu did you try?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comments. I'm using the latest version of LXLE, which uses the ubuntu 16.04 platform, I beleive. Yes, I shut down normally. I followed the advice given on these pages to stop fsck running by putting a 0 (I think) in the tune2fs command, but it didn't stop fsck running. I'm pretty confused as to what to do next. After over a minute of waiting then letters come up on boot saying system clear and so many files scanned and OK, then it boots up normally.